# Sort List by Object type property using extension method - Asp.Net Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created an API using ASP.Net Core 6. This API used to manipulate the store products. The getAllProducts endpoint returns the list of products and I have added the sorting functionality to the getAllProducts(list) endpoint by using an extension method.

**Product Entity:**

```
public class Product
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }  
    public virtual ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

**ProductCategory entity:**

```
public class ProductCategory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Extension method:**

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> list, string orderByProperty, bool desc)
    {
        string command = desc ? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy";
        var type = typeof(TEntity);
        var property = type.GetProperty(orderByProperty);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
        var propertyAccess = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, property);
        var orderByExpression = Expression.Lambda(propertyAccess, parameter);
        var resultExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), command, new Type[] { type, property.PropertyType },
            list.Expression, Expression.Quote(orderByExpression));
        return list.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExpression);
    }
```

I called the extension method this way.

```
productsList = productsList.AsQueryable().OrderBy("Category", true).ToList();
```

This works fine with all product entity properties except the 'Category'. It throws an exception `System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to compare two elements in the array.` when I pass 'Category' as orderByProperty. I want to customize the extension method so that if an object type property passed in, sort the list by name of the passed object. (by category name in this case). I expect your help. Thank You.

Comment: Why do you need queryable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime does not know how to compare two instances of `ProductCategory` so you need to provide a way for LINQ-to-Objects to do this. For example implementing `IComparable<ProductCategory>`:

```cs
public class ProductCategory : IComparable<ProductCategory>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CompareTo(ProductCategory? other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return 0;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return 1;
        return string.Compare(Name, other.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

Also possibly you can consider passing expression into the method:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity, TProp>(this IQueryable<TEntity> list, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProp>> selector, bool desc)
{
   // change accordingly 
}
```

With usage changed to:

```cs
productsList = productsList.AsQueryable()
    .OrderBy(p => p.Category.Name, true)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I want make the sorting dynamic. so the orderByProperty accepts as a query param. How can I change your answer to achieve that??

Comment: I changed the ProductCategory and passed the orderByProperty as a string to extension method. It is working perfectly. Huge thanks to you!

Comment: @Pearl was glad to help! As for the previous question - I usually maintain some kind of mapping from string to expression or ordered queryable.